Is there a way to determine the seasonal order (P, D, Q)[m] for a SARIMAX model without using Auto ARIMA or exhaustive combination search?
I am trying to perform time series modeling using SARIMAX from statsmodel library with Python as the programming language.
With ARIMA, I learned the arbitrary way of determining the non-seasonal order (p, d, and q) by looking at significant peaks of ACF and PACF (excluding the first or 0th peak).
However, for SARIMAX, I cannot find a conclusive way of finding the seasonal order (P, D, Q)[m]. Although, I know that m is the frequency of the data (e.g., 4 for quarterly, 12 for monthly). Many answers from related questions I saw were suggesting using Auto ARIMA. However, I would like to first obtain the seasonal order without it to see the difference of the model with seasonal order based on my own intuition and what was suggested from the output of Auto ARIMA.
With that said, is there a way to determine the seasonal order (P, D, Q)[m] for a SARIMAX model without using Auto ARIMA or exhaustive combination search?
